# Moving window Autocorrelation. One pass algorithm. Speed and Stability concerns

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, statistics, time-series

Helllo,

I have a timeseries `x` for which I want to generate a 'moving window autocorrelation at lag 1' series using a window of size `window_size` and a step of size `window_step`.
I have written the following one pass algorithm code (in MATLAB) for evaluating AC at lag 1:

```
function AC_timeseries = rolling_autocorr_lag1(x, window_size, window_step)
   
    N = length(x);
    
    sum_x = zeros(1, N);
    sum_x(1) = x(1);
    sum_xy = zeros(1, N);

    for n = 2: N
        sum_x(n) = sum_x(n - 1) + x(n);
        sum_xy(n) = sum_xy(n - 1) + x(n) * x(n - 1);
    end
    
    % Get the indices at which to calculate autocorrelation lag 1 values
    window_ends_idx = window_size: window_step: length(x);
    
    % Preallocate array for storing autocorrelation lag 1 time series
    AC_timeseries = zeros(1, length(window_ends_idx));

    % Generate autocorrelation lag 1 time series
    for i = 1: length(window_ends_idx)
        idx = window_ends_idx(i);
        if i == 1
            sum_use = sum_x(idx);
        else
            sum_use = sum_x(idx) - sum_x(idx - window_size);
        end
        sum_x_lag1 = sum_use - x(idx);
        sum_x_fwd1 = sum_use - x(idx - window_size + 1);
        sum_xy_window = sum_xy(idx) - sum_xy(idx - window_size + 1);
        std_dev_window = std(x(idx - window_size + 1: idx));
        N = window_size - 1;
        % Calculate autocorrelation lag 1 for the window
        AC_timeseries(i) = (N * sum_xy_window - sum_x_lag1 * sum_x_fwd1) / (N * std_dev_window * N * std_dev_window);
    end

end
```

**My Concerns:**

I would first like to know if this code can be improved further to speed up computations. Also, if a better method is available please let me know.
Also, I am sceptical that the variable sum_xy can overflow. How can I tackle this issue.

Is normalization of the data something that could help here? Can I make changes to the calculations/assignments to make this faster?

Reading online gives me the hint that extending matlab using C++ could give me speed gains here. (Unfortunately, I don't know C++). If this is possible please provide relevant code.

**Edit1:** Example inputs:

```
n = 10000000;
timeseries = randi(1000, 1, n);

window_size = floor(n * 0.03);
window_step = floor(window_size * (1 / 100));

AC_timeseries = rolling_autocorr_lag1(timeseries, window_size, window_step);
```

Comment: It will be easier for us to help if you provide (small) example inputs and ouput, and explain what the code should do. What are the meanings of "size" and "step"?

Comment: This code looks fast, and if the sums are the default double-precision floats (I don't program in matlab, so I'm not sure), then you wouldn't have to worry about overflow except under very special circumstances.  Are you sure you wrote this?  This code looks like it was written by someone who knew the answers to these questions already.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thanks for the feedback! That is quite reassuring. Indeed, I wrote it. I used the wikipedia page on pearson's coefficient as reference.

Comment: @MattTimmermans is there anything that I can do to improve speed? Reading online gives me the hint that extending matlab using C++ could give me speed gains here. (Unfortunately, I don't know C++) My application is really time critical!

Comment: @Atharva time critical applications are not written in matlab!

Comment: @AhmedAEK Oops! I actually started my research using MATLAB. Now I need to finish up and don't have the time to learn enough C++ to make real improvements here.

Comment: Usually matlab is used for research, to make sure your math is right.  It usually can't be made available where your algorithm is *deployed*, so the production version is written in something else.  How do you need to deploy this time-sensitive algorithm?

Comment: @MattTimmermans I require it for research. I have developed a technique which requires calculation of moving window statistics. The faster I can calculate these statistics the more elaborate and ambitious my main technique computations can be, otherwise some compromises have to be made. I want to study the behavior of my technique with large amounts of data. For that I require fast calculation of moving window statistics.

Comment: IC.  Well, if you really need this to be as fast as possible in matlab, then you need to replace all of your loops with built-in vector operations.  There are enough of them available that you can probably do it.  As I said, I am not really a matlab programmer, so I'll have to think about whether or not I can be enough help to write an answer.

Comment: If you need to compute autocorrelation for many lags, use the FFT approach to compute the full autocorrelation function. Some of the loops can be easily vectorized (when the vectorized code is shorter and easier to read, it likely is also a bit faster). For example `sum_x = cumsum(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question on the MATLAB forum as well. I got a great solution from user @BrunoLuong. Which can be found [here](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2010292-moving-window-autocorrelation-one-pass-algorithm-speed-and-stability-concerns#comment_2854067).

The altered code is ~20x faster! I am putting his code below as well.

```
function AC_timeseries = rolling_autocorr_lag1_BLU(x, window_size, window_step)
    sum_x = [0 cumsum(x)];
    sum_x2 = [0 cumsum(x.^2)];
    sum_xy = [0, cumsum(x(2:end).*x(1:end-1))];
    
    % Get the indices at which to calculate autocorrelation lag 1 values
    window_ends_idx = window_size: window_step: length(x);
    
    % Generate autocorrelation lag 1 time series
    N = window_size - 1;
    idx = window_ends_idx;
    iwin1 = idx - window_size + 1;
    sum_use = sum_x(idx+1) - sum_x(iwin1);
    sum_x_lag1 = sum_use - x(idx);
    sum_x_fwd1 = sum_use - x(iwin1);
    sum_xy_window = sum_xy(idx) - sum_xy(iwin1);
    sum_x2_window = sum_x2(idx+1) - sum_x2(iwin1);
    var_dev_window = (sum_x2_window - sum_use.^2/window_size); % N * square of std_dev_window
    % Calculate autocorrelation lag 1 for the window
    AC_timeseries = (N*sum_xy_window - sum_x_lag1.*sum_x_fwd1) ./ (N * var_dev_window);
end
```

Comment: I am leaving this question open for the next few days. If I get a better solution, I will accept that as the solution, otherwise, I will accept this one.